# how to make text editing in the following way in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a text file in the following format

```
some_text_1_1 | some_text_2_1 | some_text_3_1
some_text_1_2 | some_text_2_2 | some_text_3_2
some_text_1_3 | some_text_2_3 | some_text_3_3
...
```

And I want to transform it into the following

```
[
    {"a": "some_text_1_1", "b":"some_text_2_1", "c":"some_text_3_1"},
    {"a": "some_text_1_2", "b":"some_text_2_2", "c":"some_text_3_2"},
    {"a": "some_text_1_3", "b":"some_text_2_3", "c":"some_text_3_3"},
   ...
]
```

Is there a convenient way (such as through multi-cursor or block editing editing etc., NOT through regex if possible) to achieve that in vscode?

Comment: You can use Python to do the work with just a few lines of code! Are you familiar with using Python?

Comment: yes, i know, but would find a simpler way to do that, rather than write a python program to read/write a file.

Comment: Are they always 3 segments long per line?  Then it is easy with a find and replace - but that includes a simple regex ;}.

Comment: @Mark: what is the simple regex as you said (particularly when there are more than 3 segments in your terminology)? i found the regex is not always simple.

Comment: I said there is an easy regex when there are 3 segments per line.  How many segments do you have per line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the multi-cursor option. Put a cursor on every one of those lines (method may vary depending on bound keystrokes but I use Ctrl-Alt-DownArrow to extend the cursor down).

Then press Home and start typing:

```
{"a": "<right-arrow to before' |'><del x 2>", "b": ... and so on.
```

Then you just need to wrap it in `[ ]`.

Note that right-arrow method is if all your items are same size as per the question. If they are *different* sizes, you'll need to use different cursor movement commands such as Ctrl-RightArrow.

Comment: `<right-arrow to before' |` how to do this if `some_text_1_*` all have different number of words? (if they have the same number words, I can use jump words easily)

Comment: @QiangLi: there are other movement commands you can use such as the word movement ones (Ctrl-arrows). Will update answer.

Comment: what if not only different sizes, but also the number of words is different too, in that case, I can only rely on the bar character `|` to know the delimiter, rather than using ctrl-RightArrow. How do you advice to cope with that issue?

Comment: @QiangLi: I advise you include that information in the question when you ask it, so that there aren't long back-and-forth discussions about introducing arbitrary rules in a piecemeal manner :-) What if some items are split across multiple lines, what if some have four sections rather than three, what if you're allowed `\|` *within* an item? The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1):

The extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) could help.

I would suggest start with the `c` column.

- Place cursors at the start of the lines
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move twice to the next `|`
- with `Shift+End` select the c-text
- `Ctrl+X`
- type `, "c":"Ctrl+V"},` `Ctrl+V` is the key to past text
- type `Home` to go to start of line
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move to the next `|`
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors**
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move to the next `|`
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors**
- `Ctrl+X`
- type `, "b":"Ctrl+V"` `Ctrl+V` is the key to past text
- type `Home` to go to start of line
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors**
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move to the next `|`
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors**
- `Ctrl+X`
- type `{ "a":"Ctrl+V"` `Ctrl+V` is the key to past text

The regex to search for is `\|` because `|` is a special char in regex